# Loading App Store page in correct language (external browser or SKStoreProductViewController)

Tags: ios, url, browser, localization

My application supports several languages and has App Store page in corresponding languages.

I can open a language specific page in macOS browser (Safari and FireFox) by specifying an appropriate URL (e.g. https://apps.apple.com/es/app/id0000000000?mt=8).

However when I run my iOS app in Xcode with specific locale and open the page, using either SKStoreProductViewController, or UIApplication.openURL (with appropriate URL), it always shows the English page (the app's default language), even though the controls (e.g. 'Done' button in  SKStoreProductViewController) appear localised.

Tried running from the phone with unspecified locale using  correct language and corresponding country in system Settings - same appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar issue with localization(not with SKStoreProductViewController). Few strings were localized and few are not. This issue was reported from one device but it worked fine on other devices(hence later issue marked as low priority). Could you please try loading the app in another device.

Comment: All three of my devices work the same. Actually, I can't see why it should depend on device rather than on iOS version.

Comment: In my answer `Device` I mean iOS version sorry for the confusion. Do you have different iOS versions in all three devices? @cyanide